# ERROR:There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'User name'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

CONTROLLER CODE

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        IdentityUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var account = new RegisterBusiness();
        account.AddUserToRole(UserName, RoleName);

        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

        // prepopulat roles for the view dropdown
        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        var users = context.Users.OrderBy(r => r.UserName).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.Id }).ToList();
        ViewBag.users1 = users;

        return View("ManageUserRoles");
    }
```

VIEW CODE

```
 Username : @Html.DropDownList("User name",  (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.users1, "Select ...")<br />
```

There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'User name'.

Comment: The error means that the value of `ViewBag.users1` is `null`. Debug your code!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the overload you are using is looking for the viewbag reference in the first supplied property, "User Name".

Can you try this?

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("users1", null, "Select...")
```

Controller:
Change your Selectlist creation to this:

```
var users = new SelectList(context.Users.Select(rr => new { Value = rr.Id.toString(), Text = rr.Id.toString() }).OrderBy(r => r.Id), "users1", "Text", "Value" );
```

It may also be the fact that you are going to a different view:

```
return View("ManageUserRoles");
```

In this case, try something like this:
In your ManagerUserRoles controller...

```
public ActionResult ManageUserRoles()
{
    ViewBag.users1 = new SelectList(context.Users.Select(rr => new { Value = rr.Id.toString(), Text = rr.Id.toString() }).OrderBy(r => r.Id), "users1", "Text", "Value" );

    return View();

}
```